"personal access" and "password grant" clients table not being created when I run "php artisan passport:install"
When I run php artisan passport:install, it reaches the point where it asks, "Would you like to create the 'personal access' and 'password grant' clients? (yes/no)". When I respond with "yes", I encounter an error during the table creation process. For reference, I am using Laravel 11.0.8.
The error is as follows:

Illuminate\Database\QueryException
SQLSTATE[01000]: Warning: 1265 Data truncated for column 'id' at row 1
(SQL: insert into oauth_clients (user_id, name, secret,
provider, redirect, personal_access_client, password_client,
revoked, id, updated_at, created_at) values (?, Project
Personal Access Client, uEEJLJEJWLEEjn7HUsXOWjakEjO2bPBcH1mHKHDK, ?,
http://localhost, 1, 0, 0, 9bca8777-9713-4a42-9aa7-7089781971212,
2024-04-12 17:03:25, 2024-04-12 17:03:25))

I expected the tables to be created successfully and the Client ID and Client secret to be generated.

run php artisan migrate:fresh, then php artisan passport:install.

If you have modified any migrations, you might need to refresh your database. Be aware that this will erase all data in the database. You can refresh migrations and seed data (if any) by running:
php artisan migrate:fresh
